# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided...does not match the recipient window's origin Tumblr

Tags: html, dom, tumblr, postmessage

Hello I'm trying to add a Page on Tumblr but it is refusing to save, and when I inspect the element it gives me the error:

Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('http:/doofcastiel.tumblr.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https:/assets.txmblr.com').
I understand from researching it that the problem is with the http vs https but I don't know where to go in the code to change it.

```html
<html>
<head>
 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide").show();
 
   $('.show_hide').toggle(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv").slideDown(
         function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       $(".slidingDiv").slideUp(
       function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
       }
       );
   });
});
</script>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $(".slidingDiv1").hide();
   $(".show_hide1").show();
 
   $('.show_hide1').toggle(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv1").slideDown(
         function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       $(".slidingDiv1").slideUp(
       function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
       }
       );
   });
});
</script>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $(".slidingDiv2").hide();
   $(".show_hide2").show();
 
   $('.show_hide2').toggle(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv2").slideDown(
         function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       $(".slidingDiv2").slideUp(
       function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
       }
       );
   });
});
</script>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $(".slidingDiv3").hide();
   $(".show_hide3").show();
 
   $('.show_hide3').toggle(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv3").slideDown(
         function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       $(".slidingDiv3").slideUp(
       function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
       }
       );
   });
});
</script>
 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $(".slidingDiv4").hide();
   $(".show_hide4").show();
 
   $('.show_hide4').toggle(function(){
       $(".slidingDiv4").slideDown(
         function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
         }
       );
   },function(){
       $(".slidingDiv4").slideUp(
       function(){
           $("#navigation").text("navigation")
       }
       );
   });
});
</script>
 
 
 
<title>this is the page title</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
 
<style type="text/css">
 
 
::selection {background: #f8f8f8; color:#444444;}
::-moz-selection {background: #f8f8f8; color:#444444;}
::-webkit-selection {background: #f8f8f8; color:#444444;}
 
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    background-color: #000000;
    height:30px;
    }
   
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
    background-color:#000000;
    height:5px;
    }
 
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    color:{color:Background};
    height:auto;
    width:6px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    }
 
 
body {
background-color: #F4F5D9;
}
 
 
/* these are the "normal" links, you can edit the colors */
 
/* the dropdown links are the same color unless you set a different one in the body - instructions for this inside of the first dropdown */
 
a:link, a:active, a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: #000000;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
 
a:hover {
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
-o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-9/cur817.cur), progress !important;
}
 
 
 
strong, b {
 
}
 
em, i {}
 
blockquote {
text-align: justify;
}
 
 
/* this color goes in the dropdown links lines and also around the dropdown contents */
 
.dropdown {
background-color: #F8F8F8;
padding: 20px;
}
 
 
/* you can change align left to center in the following label for the dropdown links */
 
.dropdown a {
display: inline;
font-family: 'Tahoma';
font-size: 10px;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
-moz-transition:0.2s ease-in;
-webkit-transition:0.2s ease-in;
-o-transition:0.2s ease-in;
transition:0.2s ease-in;
opacity: 1;
}
 
 
/* you can put opacity 1 here too if you don't want the dropdown links to fade away when hovering them */
 
.dropdown a:hover {
opacity: .5;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
cursor: url(http://cur.cursors-4u.net/others/oth-6/oth589.cur), progress !important;
}
 
 
/* these are important, don't delete */
 
.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
 
.show_hide1 {
    display:none;
}
 
.show_hide2 {
    display:none;
}
 
.show_hide3 {
    display:none;
}
 
.show_hide4 {
    display:none;
}
 
 
/* the table color must be the same as the background color in the BODY label at the beginning of the CSS */
 
#table {
width: 800px;
background-color: #F4F5D9;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
padding: 0px;
}
 
/* the following go in order of appearance */
/* this is the main title, the line height makes the two lines be closer so modify it as you please */
 
#title {
font-family: "Helvetica";
background-color: #e0b8e3;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 90%;
color: #333333;
}
 
.description {
font-family: "Tahoma";
font-size: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333333;
text-align: center;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
letter-spacing: 2px;
padding: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
}
 
/* here's a dropdown as you can see, in the page theme itself i mean */
 
.header {
font-family: "Tahoma";
font-size: 8px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333333;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
letter-spacing: 2px;
padding: 10px;
font-weight: bold;
}
 
#box{
background-color: #eff6f8;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
width: 800px;
}
 
.content {
font-family: "Helvetica";
font-size: 11px;
color: #404040;
text-align: justify;
}
 
 
 
</style>
</head>
 
 
<body>
 
<center><div id="table"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" colspan="1">
 
<tr><td colspan="1" id="title">You and Me Against the World<br><br><small><a href ="http://doofcastiel.tumblr.com">Home</a> | <a href ="http://bypinksman.tumblr.com/dropdowns">Credit</a></small></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="10"></td></tr>
 
 
 
<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="description">
<p>I'm always here for you no matter what you need, so don't be afraid to talk <3</p>
<!---here goes a description as long as you please. it's justified so it can contain a few lines, though you can change the alignment to centered in the css if you want to. you can also put padding: 10px; instead of 20 which is how it's now (the <em>padding</em> is the space between the text and the borders of the box)---></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="10"></td></tr>
 
 
 
 
 
<!---<tr>
<td colspan="1" class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="show_hide" style="color: #8eb4c1;">FAQ</a>
 
<div class="slidingDiv" style="background: #ffffff; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Tahoma'; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; text-align: justify; line-height: 16px;">
 
<!---<p>1. As you can see, the dropdown-link-line background is light grey and the content background is white. Around this content, there is a grey border. This light grey is #F8F8F8 and it's set in the label <em>.dropdown {}</em> in the CSS. You can either change that to <strong>#FFFFFF</strong> (white) or change the white to grey. How to change the white to grey? Go to the theme code and find this text. Right above this text, there is a code that says <strong>class slidingDiv</strong> and next to it <strong>style background: #FFFFFF</strong> so change this code to #F8F8F8 to set the background color to light grey. All of this is optional, obviously.</p>
 
<p>2. The dropdown links are the same color as the "normal" links <a href="">this is a normal link.</a> It's possible to change that; you can even put a color per dropdown link and make a rainbow! See: again, search this text in the theme code. On top of this there is the Instruction #1 and then the <strong>slidingDiv</strong> code, and then <strong>class <em>show_hide</em></strong> on top, right? Next to it you'll find <em>style color: #8EB4C1;</em> and that's the same color you'll find in the CSS label for the links (a:link, a:active, a:visited). So just change that color in every dropdown link or in all of them to set different colors.</p>
 
<p>3. In the previous Instruction you can see that <a href="">the normal link</a> looks like the dropdown links. Unfortunately, I don't know how to change that. All you can do is change the size and the font of the dropdown links in <strong>class slidingDiv</strong> and enter a less thick font (but the dropdown links font will be modified as well).</p>
 
<p>4. Feel free to ask anything else - not too complicated stuff, I mean the theme is just the way it is. I separated the codes for every part of the structure so you can delete dropdowns in case five are too much, or titles, description, etc. and know exactly where every part begins and ends. You can change colors, fonts, ... please don't remove the credit though! I think that's all :) oh and remember to enter your url in the ask box code at the bottom of the page, where it says <em>YOURURLHERE.tumblr.com</em> aaaand here is a tutorial for installing dropdowns and more than one dropdown in the same page <a href="http://(adfly)/6004008/itsphotoshop.com/post/68286752700/tutorial-asked-by-anonymous-live-preview-of-this" target="_blank">(x)</a></p>
 
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="20"></td></tr>--->
 
 
 
 
 
<!---<tr><td colspan="1" class="header">
here goes an optional title</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="10"></td></tr>--->
 
<!---<tr></tr><td colspan="1" class="content" id="box">
FAQ
<!---and here goes some optional, additional, static content and <a href="">this is a link.</a> again, feel free to change alignment to centered in the css</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="20"></td></tr>--->
 
 
 
 
 
<tr><td colspan="1" class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="show_hide1" style="color: #A77DC2;">Can We Be Friends?</a>
 
<div class="slidingDiv1" style="background: #ffffff; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Tahoma'; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; text-align: justify; line-height: 16px;"><p>YES ❤ a thousand times yes! Just start a convo and I'll pick up like we've been friends for years.</p>
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="10"></td></tr>
 
 
 
 
 
<tr><td colspan="1" class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="show_hide2" style="color: #A77DC2;">But What Do I Talk About?</a>
 
<div class="slidingDiv2" style="background: #ffffff; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Tahoma'; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; text-align: justify; line-height: 16px;"><p>I'll respond to whatever you send hun and if I don't it means tumblr was a poop and you should send it again. I suggest maybe visiting <a href ="doofcastiel.tumblr.com/tags">my tag page</a> and looking through my fandoms and ships so we can freak out together. If not then funny stories, sad stories, what you did today, favorite song/band, the list is endless babes. Whatever you have to say I'd love to here it. 
-ps if you mention destiel and/or cecilos I will melt (✿◠‿◠) -
</p>
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="10"></td></tr>
 
 
 
 
 
<tr><td colspan="1" class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="show_hide3" style="color: #A77DC2;">Hate</a>
 
<div class="slidingDiv3" style="background: #ffffff; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Tahoma'; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; text-align: justify; line-height: 16px;"><p>I will not tolerate any hate messages. If you send one I will use tumblr's block method to figure out who you are, and I will post the message with your url. Save everyone the trouble and DON'T DO IT.</p>
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="10"></td></tr>
 
 
 
 
 
<!---<tr><td colspan="1" class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="show_hide4" style="color: #8eb4c1;">4. title</a>
 
<div class="slidingDiv4" style="background: #ffffff; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Tahoma'; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; text-align: justify; line-height: 16px;"><p>content here</p>
</div></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="20"></td></tr>--->
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
<tr><td colspan="1" class="header">
If you want me to answer privately add an asterisk (*) to the beginnging otherwise I answer publicly</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="1" height="10"></td></tr>
 
 
 
<tr><td colspan="1" class="content" id="box"><!---<p>and some text here before the ask box</p>--->
 
 
<p align="center"><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="190" src="http://www.tumblr.com/ask_form/doofcastiel.tumblr.com" style="background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" id="ask_form"></iframe><!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('ask_form').allowTransparency=true;</script><![endif]--></p>

<p><iframe id="submit_form" src="http://www.tumblr.com/submit_form/doofcastiel.tumblr.com" frameborder="0" height="500" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe><!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('submit_form').allowTransparency=true;</script><![endif]--></p>
 
 
 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</center>
 
<div style="background-color: #ffffff; border: 1px solid #ebebeb; padding: 2px; font-family: 'Times'; font-size: 6px; float: right; position: fixed; bottom: 3px; right: 3px; text-transform:uppercase;"><a href="http://bypinksman.tumblr.com">PNKSMN</a></div>
 
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: If you use: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js`, it should work. Anything that is not hosted on Tumblr's servers, needs to be served via **HTTPS**

Comment: @mikedidthis but it is hosted on tumblr its doofcastiel.tumblr.com and none of my other pages are having this problem. Also what would I have to do with that link? (edit: when I inspect the element it's now telling me there is a 500 internal server error whenever I click save)

Comment: The `jQuery` file isn't hosted on Tumblr, you need to serve it via `https`.

Comment: ok I replaced it and it still wont work. this is the 500 internal servor error I'm getting

Comment: POST https://www.tumblr.com/customize_api/blog/doofcastiel/pages 500 (Internal Server Error) J.cors.e.crossDomain.send et.extend.ajax t.ajax t.sync Backbone.Model.extend.sync n.extend.save h.save_page u  t.Events.trigger Tumblr.Customize.EditPageView.Tumblr.Customize.PanelView.extend.save_page t et.event.dispatch m.handle

Comment: sorry if I'm not making this any easier

Comment: No, I apologise, its my fault. I missed the `iframes` for the ask / submit box. They should both be `https` as well. Works fine here, make sure you are using the **custom layout**: http://mikedidthis-dev.tumblr.com/darci

Comment: Thanks you so much that worked perfectly! Did you just change the https for the ask/submit box to fix it?

Comment: Yep! :D Glad to help. Today we both learned to `https` all the things!